# json problem in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "tiles/chartValue.php",
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){                
                $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
                  alert(key + ': ' + value); 
                });
                       });
                });
```

Here is chartValue.php

```
<?php
    include("../functions.php");
    $DAO=new DBUtil();
    $DAO->initDB("../db/connection.properties");
    $k=$DAO->getChart();
    echo json_encode($k);
?>
```

here is the getChart function of functions.php

```
public function getChart()
{
    $sql = "SELECT a.total, round( (b.active *100) / total ) active_user, round( (c.inactive *100) / total ) inactive_user
        FROM 
        (               
            SELECT IFNULL( count( * ) , 0 ) total FROM ashekan_info
        )a, 
        (               
            SELECT IFNULL( count( * ) , 0 ) active FROM ashekan_info WHERE is_active =1
        )b, 
        (               
            SELECT IFNULL( count( * ) , 0 ) inactive FROM ashekan_info  WHERE is_active =0
        )c";

        $result=mysql_query($sql,$this->connect()) or die(mysql_error());   
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $json = array('total'       =>$row['total'],
                  'active_user' =>$row['active_user'],
                  'inactive_user'   =>$row['inactive_user']
                 ); 
        return $json;

}
```

I get the result in firebug is {"total":"1","active_user":"0","inactive_user":"100"}

problem is it shows each character in alert box. i.e : {, ", t and so on.

how can i get 1, 0, 100 ? thanks in advance.

Comment: try `alert(typeof(data));` ... is it object ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess...

You have `datatype: 'json'`, but JS is case sensitive, and the correct parameter is `dataType`. So it's ignoring that, taking text, and your `each` call is iterating through characters of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Because the answer you get from your AJAX call is still a string.
Parse it first with [JQuery.ParseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), then iterate the parsed variable.

Comment: Didn't occur to me, since the content type header isn't visibly set in the snippet either.

Answer (score 0):

what I think you need is :

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

right before

```
echo json_encode($k);
```